# HOW TO SUM THE SPLIT BASED ON AGENT_RANKING

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
POL_NO  AGENT   AGENT_RANKING   SPLIT
100     001      1.1            0.1500
100     002      1.2            0.5000
100     003      1.3            0.3500
100     004      2.1            0.1500
100     005      2.2            0.5000
100     006      2.3            0.2500
100     007      3.1            0.5000
100     008      3.2            0.5000
```

BASED ON AGENT_RANKING(1.1 TO 1.3 and 3.1 TO 3.2) SUM OF THE SPLIT SHOULD BE 1.0000.I WANT TO POPULATE THE BELOW RESULT.CAN ANYONE HELP?
P.S. CAN IT BE DONE USING LOOP?

RESULT:

```
POL_NO  AGENT   AGENT_RANKING   SPLIT
100     001      1.1            0.1500
100     002      1.2            0.5000
100     003      1.3            0.3500
100     007      3.1            0.5000
100     008      3.2            0.5000
```

Comment: you should explain more , expected result can populate by this query :
select * from table where AGENT_RANKING < 2

Comment: @cchajar The OP want to `SUM OF THE SPLIT SHOULD BE 1.0000.`,so I think the key point is make group by `AGENT_RANKING ` then check the sum is 1

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE TABLE TO BE MORE SPECIFIC.USING FLOOR WE CAN EXRACT THE INTEGER PART (FOR EG. 1 FROM 1.1 THEN WE NEED TO CALCULATE THE SUM OF THE SUM OF THE DECIMAL PART SAY (.1,.2,.3 WHICH SHOULD BE EQUAL TO 1.0000) @cchajar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
pol_no int,
agent Char(3),
agent_ranking Float,
split Decimal(5,4)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values

(100,'001',1.1,0.1500),
(100,'002',1.2,0.5000),
(100,'003',1.3,0.3500),
(100,'004',2.1,0.1500),
(100,'005',2.2,0.5000),
(100,'006',2.3,0.2500),
(100,'007',3.1,0.5000),
(100,'008',3.2,0.5000)
;
```

Query:

```
With cte As
(
Select 
  *,
  Sum(split) over (partition by pol_no, Floor(agent_ranking)) as splitsum
From #tbl
)
Select * From cte Where splitsum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gap and island problem.
You can try to make a row number to represent the group.

using `SUM` get total by the group number then do join again.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY floor(cast(AGENT_RANKING as money)),POL_NO order by AGENT_RANKING) -
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY POL_NO order by AGENT_RANKING) grp
    FROM T
),CTE2 AS (
    SELECT grp
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY grp
    HAVING SUM(SPLIT) = 1
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM CTE t1 JOIN CTE2 t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6c17910e4deae2d94e0f81f6235f0617)

Answer (score 0):

Your results can be returned with:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.agent_ranking between 1.1 and 1.3;
```

The splits already sum to 1.  If you wanted to guarantee that, you can recalculate them using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       ( split / sum(split) over (partition by pol_no) ) as new_split
from t
where t.agent_ranking between 1.1 and 1.3;
```

If you just want the initial agents where the sum is 1, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(split) over (partition by pol_no order by agent_ranking) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where (running_sum - split) < 1
order by pol_no, agent_ranking;
```

This returns the first three agents, because their sum is the first to hit or exceed 1.